# How can we construct a differential equation from a system of differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a linear differential equation of order $n$. All of us know how to write it down as a system of linear differential equation as $X' = A_{n \times n} X_{n \times 1}$.

My question is about the converse. I am not getting a satisfactory answer anywhere.

**Suppose an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is given. How can we construct a linear differential equation of order $n$ whose matrix representation is $X' = AX ? Is it always possible?**

My intuition is **NO**. But I can not explain it properly. If possible please give an example explaining the process. If not possible give a proof or counterexample.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Look up the "cyclic vector" method (CVM) and the Danilevski-Barkatou-Zürcher algorithm
(DBZ), e.g. see Bostan,Chyzak, and Panafieu, [Complexity Estimates for Two Uncoupling Algorithms, 2013.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5414) and Kovacic, [Cyclic Vectors And Picard-Vessiot Extensions (1996).](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.1763)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, if you are allowed to do coordinate transformations. In this case you can do it if

1. Either $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, or
2. If $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue, then that eigenvalue has only one eigenvector.

Under these conditions, you can transform A to the form
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0& \cdots &0 \\0&0&1&\cdots &0\\ 0&0&0&\ddots&0\\0&0&0&\cdots &1\\
-d_1&-d_2&-d_3&\cdots & -d_n}$$

One way to find the transformation, is to start with a vector $b$ and calculating $A b$, $A^2b$ through $A^{n-1}b$. Then the transformation matrix is given by
$$
T=\pmatrix{b &A b &A^2 b& \cdots & A^{n-1}b } \tag 1$$
One can show that under the stated assumptions, there exists a $b$ so that the above matrix is invertible.

**Added in response to comments**

The following statements are equivalent:

- A system of $n$ first order linear differential equation of the form $dX/dt = A X$ can be converted to $$
  \frac{d^n y}{d t^n} + a_1 \frac{d^{n-1} y}{d t^{n-1}} + a_2 \frac{d^{n-2} y}{d t^{n-2}}\cdots + a_0 = 0$$
- There exists a non-zero vector, $c$, so that the matrix $Q$ defined below has full rank
  $$
  Q = \pmatrix{c \\c A \\\vdots\\ c A^{n-1} }$$
- There exists a vector $b$ so that the matrix $T$ defined in (1) is full rank.
- The minimal polynomial of $A$ is equal to its characteristic polynomial
- The two conditions mentioned at the start of his answer hold

Refer to any standard *Modern Control Theory* book for proof of the above. THe requirement for $T$ to be full rank is called *controllability* condition and the requirement that $Q$ be full rank is called *observability* condition.

In particular, if $A=\pm I$, the identity matrix and $n>1$ then $A$ does not satisfy the last condition and hence it is not possible to transform $X'= \pm X$.

Comment: If we allow transformation then it may work but not possible for an arbitrary matrix. We can solve the system $X' = AX$ when our matrix $A$ is arbitrary.

Comment: How do you do this? May be I am misunderstanding the problem. I assume that you are given $n$ linear first order differential equation and you want **one** $n$th order differential equation. If this is the case, $A$ cannot be arbitrary. Simplest counter example is $A = I$, the identity matrix. I will edit my answer also to explain this better

Comment: We have a system of $n$ linear differential equations which can be written as $X' = AX$. Let us consider $A$ is a constant matrix chosen arbitrarily. My question is to know how we can write it down as a differential equation of order $n$. **So the answer is not possible and the counterexample is $A = I$.** Is it okay now?

Comment: That is the gist of my answer. I edited my answer to give a complete necessary and sufficient condition to be able to do it.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Where do you teach may I know? Are you working with Cryptography?